# curl load IPs from Text file

Tags: shell-script, curl

I have a list of IPs and want to run a specific `curl` command on each of them. The command is:

```
curl --user test:test http://192.168.1.1/security/pkm.html | 
    egrep '@company|config.pkm.password'
```

And I want to run it for all IPs in `IPs.txt`:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
........1.200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over each IP in your file:

```
while read IP; do 
    curl --user test:test http://"$IP"/security/pkm.html | 
        egrep '@company|config.pkm.password'
done < IPs.txt
```

In your case, where you want all IPs in a range, you could also simply do:

```
for i in {1..200}; do
    curl --user test:test http://192.168.1."$i"/security/pkm.html | 
        egrep '@company|config.pkm.password'
done
```